# How to take extract data from the remote database in Python?

Tags: python, database

I am using MySQLdb. I am developing a simple GUI application using Rpy2. What my program does?
- User can input the static data and mathematical operations will be computed using those data.
- Another thing where I am lost is, user will give the location of their database and the program will computer maths using the data from the remote database.

I have accomplished the result using the localhost. 
How can I do it from the remote database? Any idea? 
Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you establish the MySQL connection, use the remote machines IP address / hostname and corresponding credentials (username, password).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Fabian! But I am confused here? Should I allow user to upload the .csv file or is there any other way? I cannot assign static IP as the database of different users can be located in different remote machines. Hope you get me. Thank you!

Comment: Let the user enter the IP then? It's kinda hard to follow you to be honest, what .csv file do you mean?